# In a Pandas dataframe, how to filter a set of rows based on a start row and end row both satisfying different conditions?

Tags: python, pandas

In a Pandas dataframe, how to filter a set of rows based on a start row and end row both satisfying different conditions?

if one of my string columns contain a particular substring, that row is a start row. Then, if there is another row where my string column contains another substring, that row is an end row. I need a way to just filter all rows between these two.

I tried to find the start_row using,

```
start_row = df_page['StringCol'].str.contains('SubStrForStartRow')
```

This gives me a boolean series that has 'True' for my start row. But, not sure how to further achieve what I described above.

For example, Consider a dataframe as follows

```
data = [['UnwantedRow', ''],['TransactionStart', ''],['Date1', 200],['Date2', 300],['TransactionEnd', ''],['UnwantedRow','']]
df = pandas.DataFrame(data, columns=['Transaction', 'Value'])
```

Using 'Start' and 'Stop' substrings, I want to be able to filter out all rows between the 'TransactionStart' row and the 'TransactionEnd' row. That is, the two rows which contain ['Date1', 200] and ['Date2', 300] alone.

Comment: Please share a sample input and expected output for better understanding.

Comment: Thanks. Added an example in the question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return the index number of the start and end rows with `.index[0]` and filter for those rows with `iloc`. The upperbound of iloc is exclusive, which is why I use `end_row+1`:

```
data = [['UnwantedRow', ''],['TransactionStart', ''],['Date1', 200],['Date2', 300],['TransactionEnd', ''],['UnwantedRow','']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Transaction', 'Value'])
start_row = df[df['Transaction'].str.contains('TransactionStart')].index[0]
end_row =  df[df['Transaction'].str.contains('TransactionEnd')].index[0]
df = df.iloc[start_row:end_row+1]
df
Out[1]: 
        Transaction Value
1  TransactionStart      
2             Date1   200
3             Date2   300
4    TransactionEnd
```